# Prevent black band running down the screen?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, google-authentication

[image]

Logging in using [this] package causing the following behaviour. I think the darkening of the screen is expected but it's the ungraceful departure that is the problem..

I don't get an error..but this appears on the console.

```
W/ActivityThread(31387): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@a1edd0f
```

My code is the recommended code for the plugin.

```
void loginWithGoogle() async {
    var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;

    print('Signing up with google...');
    setState(() {
      _showProgressIndicator = true;
    });
    FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithGoogleAcc();
    uId = user.uid;

    if (uId != null) {
      print('Signed in: $uId');
      widget.onSignedIn(user);
    } else {
      print('google login cancelled...');
    }

    setState(() {
      _showProgressIndicator = false;
    });
  }
```

This is happening on an android device.

Comment: Have you tried if it reproduces with `master` channel? Have you tried with a different device?

Comment: no haven't tried on master ... Yep tried with many different devices. Problem persisting for a while now on different versions of flutter. `Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale en-IE)`

Comment: What kind of devices? iOS, Android, both?

Comment: just tested on Android : HTC, Samsung and an emualtor

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer logged as an issue on Github

Comment: Wondering if there's a solution for this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem and can't seem to find the above-mentioned Github issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: here is the issue on GitHub https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28882. Doesn't seem to be much movement. Maybe star it.