# Black stripe from top to bottom when Google Sign In dismissed - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin, dismiss

I am having problem when using Google Sign In option in my application. The sign in process works fine, but whenever Google pop up is dismissed, black stripe moves from the top to the bottom of the screen. I am not getting any errors and it does not effect the functionality, but I want to remove it.

I found the same issue on StackOverflow and GitHub, but I could not solve the problem. Here are links to the issues I have found:

1. [Screen flickers after Google Sign In dialog dismiss android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484002/screen-flickers-after-google-sign-in-dialog-dismiss-android-studio)
2. [Prevent black band running down the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945622/prevent-black-band-running-down-the-screen)
3. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28882

Anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: did you find any solution yet? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, I did not find solution, but I have realized that it is not happening always and on every device...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change style.xml property. Replace with this line:

```
< style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: This one solved the issue. Thank!